# mongodb cursor iteration performance issue

Tags: java, mongodb

I've a cursor which returns some documents size more than 35k. In Java I'm iterating that cursor to get documents. It's taking more than 20 sec. Any possible solution to decrease time.

my code:

```
ArrayList<DBObject> list =  new ArrayList<DBObject>()
collection = mongoDB.getCollection("locations");
cursor = collection.find();
while (cursor.hasNext()) {
  list.add(cursor.next());
}
```

Comment: How about using ["projection"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/) to limit the fields you are returning in results to only those that you need. Or at the very least how about a "query" condition to only match the documents you need since you are presently asking for every document in the collection. You are not giving enough information for people to make a real judgement here other than those basic conditions.

Answer (score 0):

As you have it, the only thing you could really do is try to combine two of those lines to reduce a little bit of the overhead.

```
ArrayList<DBObject> list =  new ArrayList<DBObject>();
cursor = mongoDB.getCollection("locations").find();
while (cursor.hasNext()) {
    list.add(cursor.next());
}
```

The issue is probably less the code and more the size of the documents. Do you need every document in the collection? Is there a way you could filter some out?

Comment: Yep I need every document in that collection and each document size and fields are also very less. here one sample :  {_id:1, location: "India", code:"0-0-1"}

Comment: around 37k documents.

Comment: That's a lot. 20 secs is about what I would expect it to take